# Why is ratio constraint not respected on iPhone XR/Xs Max?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a small `UIImageView` for displaying a user's profile photo. This looks fine on iPhone 6S, but when I run it on iPhone XR, the image is reduced to a tiny dot on the screen. I tried with simulators of different models, this problem only appears on XR/Xs Max simulators.

In the end, I found the problem: I had 2 constraints on this `UIImageView`: a width constraint of 32 points and a ratio constraint of 1. When I delete the ratio-constraint and add a height constraint of 32 points, all works fine.

I am wondering what causes iPhone XR/Xs Max to fail to respect the ratio-constraint? Is ratio constraint no longer supported in new models?

The simulators are all running iOS 12.2.

--EDIT--

Another UI layout issue only on XR/Xs Max, not related to ratio. I put a UIImageView into a container View, and set its frame like this:

```
imageView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

The imageView look fine on all other models, filling the containerView. But on XR/XsMax, there is a margin on the right and bottom:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the end, I found the problem: I had 2 constraints on this UIImageView: a width constraint of 32 points and a ratio constraint of 1.

That does work. In all probability you configured the aspect ratio constraint incorrectly.

> ```
> imageView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
> ```

Here, everything depends on *when* you say this. If you say it too early, such as in `viewDidLoad`, the `containerView` itself does not yet have its real `bounds`, so you'll end up with a wrong result. This is why using constraints is so much better. Using constraints, you can guarantee that the image view will fit its superview.

So go back to using constraints, configure the aspect ratio correctly, and all will be well.

Comment: About your first comment, I have set the constraints to position the view relative to other views. I was talking about its size constraints.

Comment: That's great, but without seeing what the constraints really are, I have no way of knowing that. You need to provide minimal verifiable reproducible code. I have no way of knowing what you are doing outside the code you actually show. If you really want good help, show enough code. As it stands, all I know is that you are wrong, i.e. ratio constraints _are_ respected. So show me _your_ constraints and I'll tell you what's wrong with them.

Comment: Thanks! About the second issue, I followed your advice,and tried constraints instead of bounds. Looks good now. I still don't understand why the code works on other models, perhaps XR uses different code logic... About the first problem, it seems  I entered number 1 in the constraint field, instead of choosing '1:1' from the drop down, I changed that, now width+ratio constraints work as expected.

Comment: Okay, I'll change my answer (sort of cheating, but it's better that we help future readers in a good way).